# Exception Handling in WCF with Enterprise Library 4.1

Tags: wcf, exception, enterprise-library

I have about 7 layers architecture in which WCF bridges between the UI and the rest of the layers.

Can I use Enterprise Library for whole across the layers?

Am I naive in using EAB (Exception Handling Application Block)?

Comment: You can handle the exception handling using `Unity` which a part of EL, as *cross cutting concern*.

Comment: Unity doesn't do any exception handling at all. You can use Unity interception to wire up the exception block, was that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

The EHAB in particular is specifically intended to be used at layer boundaries. However, you aren't very specific in your question - what have you tried? What specifically are you confused about?

Comment: I am confused about using the configuration file.I would like to run it as a single config file.I had tried to write a wrapper, library and in that library to use a config file. For eg : if the exception occurs in busniess layer or the ui layer , it will be passing the exception to the wrapper and from there it will take on. But the configuration is having some issue. Please suggest !!

Comment: Libraries don't have config files - applications do (actually AppDomains). You have to put the Entlib config into the config file for the exe (app.config or web.config).

Comment: Thanks Chris :) , appreciate that .I had tried to achive something unachivialble .I was trying to accomadate the whole architecture under one config file..Now i think its not possible..